# Where is the right place to configure the APP name?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

Each Ionic project has a project configuration file [ionic.config.json](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuration) where you can configure the human-readable name of the app:

```
{
  // The human-readable name of the app.
  "name": "My App",

  // The project type of the app. The CLI uses this value to determine which
  // commands and command options are available, what to output for help
  // documentation, and what to use for web asset builds and the dev server.
  "type": "angular",

  // The App ID for Ionic Appflow.
  "id": "abc123",

  // Configuration object for integrations such as Cordova and Capacitor.
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {
      ...
    }
  },

  // Hook configuration--see the Hooks section below for details.
  "hooks": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Using [capacitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/basics/configuring-your-app/) gives us another opportunity to place an app name:

```
{
  // The package name for Android and the bundle identifier for iOS.
  "appId": "com.company.appname",

  // Your app's name.
  "appName": "Capacitor Kitchen Sink",

  // Sets the directory of your built web assets. This is the directory that will be
  // used to run your app in a native environment.
  "webDir": "www",

  // The JavaScript package manager to use, either npm or yarn.
  "npmClient": "npm",
  ...
}
```

Where is the right place for the app name?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capacitor works with any framework, not just with Ionic, so the app name should be in the `capacitor.config.json`.

But as you said, Capacitor embraces the idea of "Code once, configure everywhere", so that `appName` is used only when you add the ios or android platforms, once you have added them you have to change the name from Xcode for iOS apps or from Android Studio for Android apps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cordova's `config.xml`. There you have the tag `<name>MyAppName</name>` for this purpose. This is the name that will finally appear under the icon.

```xml
<widget id="com.mycompany.myapppackage" version="0.0.1" versionCode="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>My App's name</name>
    <description>A nice description of my app.</description>
    <author email="mymail@myserver.com" href="https://www.myserver.com">Author's name</author>
    ...
</widget>
```

More info: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/

Comment: https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/basics/configuring-your-app Capacitor embraces the idea of "Code once, configure everywhere": configuration is managed per-platform instead of in an abstracted system like a **config.xml** in Cordova

Comment: Thanks for the link, that was interesting. Till now I have followed a Cordova point of view for my development, thus I used `config.xml`. I avoided Capacitor in favor Cordova as I consider Cordova to be more ripe and also comes from Apache, which I consider rock solid. But, if you knew where to place the app name, why you asked in first place?